# Static Matrix multiplication to dynamic matrix in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, matrix, 2d

I need to build program that make Matrix multiplication.
When i have 2 Static matrix, and the function return pointer to the new dynamic matrix.

My problem is make the multiplication right when I'm moving the matrix into a function.

Main is:

```
    int f_matrix[EX2_SIZE][EX2_SIZE] = { {1,2,3}, {1,4,7},{1,5,9} };
int s_matrix[EX2_SIZE][EX2_SIZE] = { {9,8,7},{4,5,6},{0,9,6} };
int m1_rows = EX2_SIZE, m1_cols = EX2_SIZE; 
int m2_rows = EX2_SIZE, m2_cols = EX2_SIZE; //For tester can change easily
int **new_matrix;

if (m1_rows != m2_rows || m1_cols != m2_cols) return 0;  //For multiplying must be equal matrix !!

new_matrix = multiplying(f_matrix, s_matrix, m1_rows, m1_cols);
print_mtrx(new_matrix, m1_rows, m1_cols);
free_mtrx(new_matrix, m1_cols);
```

The problem is in the "multiplying" function, and here is it:

```
int multiplying(int **A, int **B, int rows, int cols) {
int **C;
int i,j;
C = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*rows);
for (i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
    C[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*cols);
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            C[i][j] = (A[i][j]) * (B[i][j]);
}

return C;
}
```

THX

Comment: Shouldn't in for be `rows` instead of `cols`? `C = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*rows);
for (i = 0; i < cols; i++) {`... Becouse if `cols` > `rows` -> UB

Comment: `int multiplying(int **A, int **B, int rows, int cols)` -> `int **multiplying(int rows, int cols, int (*A)[cols], int (*B)[cols])`

Comment: 2D-Array is not double pointer.

Comment: A double-pointer cannot point to a 2D array, these are different things.

Comment: You don't do matrix multiplication by multiplying corresponding elements.  Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication to see how it's really done.

Comment: `fun(a[ROWS][COLS])`...this way you can pass it to another function.

Comment: @coderredoc only when `ROWS` and `COLS` are compile-time constants.

Comment: @FelixPalmen.: Yes. Otherwise you can't do it like this.

Comment: @coderredoc you can with VLAs, see my comment above. (of course, the canonic warning about them being optional in C11 applies)

Comment: @FelixPalmen.: Ah yes but I didn't mean that..I simply meant that this form (specifying the row and column sizes) is possible when you have static constraints.

Comment: @FelixPalmen.: If you have some time can I have a short work related discussion with you? http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=hackerrank This site is for programmers discussion. Please come if you can for some time.

Comment: @FelixPalmen.: I was thinking about a discussion about one of your project with you. If you don't mind please join once to have a short discussion.

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < cols; i++) {` --> `for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming C99 (or C11 and the implementation does not define `__STDC_NO_VLA__`), then the simplest approach is use variable length arrays (VLAs) and to have the calling code allocate the space for the result matrix too.  To multiply two matrices, `A[M][N]` and `B[P][Q]` in that order, the values of `N` and `P` must be equal and the result matrix is `C[M][Q]`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static
void matrix_multiply(int A_rows, int A_cols, int B_cols,
                     int A[A_rows][A_cols],
                     int B[A_cols][B_cols],
                     int C[A_rows][B_cols])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < A_rows; i++)
    {
         for (int j = 0; j < B_cols; j++)
         {
              int sum = 0;
              for (int k = 0; k < A_cols; k++)
                  sum += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
              C[i][j] = sum;
         }
    }
}

static void print_matrix(const char *tag, int w, int N, int M, int matrix[N][M])
{
    printf("%s (%dx%d):\n", tag, N, M);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
         for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
             printf("%*d", w, matrix[i][j]);
         putchar('\n');
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int A[3][4] =
    {
        { 41, 76, 70, 42, },
        { 70, 62, 77, 74, },
        { 49, 55, 43, 65, },
    };
    int B[4][5] =
    {
        { 73, 33, 42, 72, 65, },
        { 69, 30, 83, 83, 64, },
        { 90, 74, 84, 51, 23, },
        { 62, 45, 84, 46, 43, },
    };
    int C[3][5];
    print_matrix("A", 3, 3, 4, A);
    print_matrix("B", 3, 4, 5, B);
    matrix_multiply(3, 4, 5, A, B, C);
    print_matrix("C", 6, 3, 5, C);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
A (3x4):
 41 76 70 42
 70 62 77 74
 49 55 43 65
B (4x5):
 73 33 42 72 65
 69 30 83 83 64
 90 74 84 51 23
 62 45 84 46 43
C (3x5):
 17141 10703 17438 14762 10945
 20906 13198 20770 17517 13471
 15272  9374 15695 13276 10489
```

If you want to do dynamic memory allocation, then I think you have to pass a pointer to a pointer to a VLA array to the function to get the value returned.  That leads to code like this, which is very similar to the previous code — except for the (unchecked) memory allocation.  Note that because this uses `static_assert`, it is a C11 program, not a C99 program.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef __STDC_NO_VLA__      // C11
static_assert(0, "No VLA support");
#endif

static void matrix_multiply(int A_rows, int A_cols, int B_cols,
                            int A[A_rows][A_cols], int B[A_cols][B_cols],
                            int (**C)[B_cols])
{
    (*C) = malloc(sizeof(int [A_rows][B_cols]));  // XXX: Check memory allocation!
    for (int i = 0; i < A_rows; i++)
    {
         for (int j = 0; j < B_cols; j++)
         {
              int sum = 0;
              for (int k = 0; k < A_cols; k++)
                  sum += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
              (*C)[i][j] = sum;
         }
    }
}

static void print_matrix(const char *tag, int w, int N, int M, int matrix[N][M])
{
    printf("%s (%dx%d):\n", tag, N, M);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
         for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
             printf("%*d", w, matrix[i][j]);
         putchar('\n');
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    enum { N = 3, M = 4, P = 4, Q = 5 };
    int A[N][M] =
    {
        { 41, 76, 70, 42, },
        { 70, 62, 77, 74, },
        { 49, 55, 43, 65, },
    };
    int B[P][Q] =
    {
        { 73, 33, 42, 72, 65, },
        { 69, 30, 83, 83, 64, },
        { 90, 74, 84, 51, 23, },
        { 62, 45, 84, 46, 43, },
    };
    static_assert(M == P, "Matrix dimensions are mismatched");
    int (*C)[Q];
    print_matrix("A", 3, N, M, A);
    print_matrix("B", 3, P, Q, B);
    matrix_multiply(N, M, Q, A, B, &C);
    print_matrix("C", 6, N, Q, C);
    free(C);
    return 0;
}
```

This produces the same output as before, of course.

---

#### Analyzing original code

Here's a fixed variant of your original code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void free_mtrx(int **mtrx, int rows)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        free(mtrx[i]);
    free(mtrx);
}

static int **multiplying_1(int **A, int **B, int rows, int cols)
{
    int **C;
    C = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *) * rows);
    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
    {
        C[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * cols);
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            C[i][j] = (A[i][j]) * (B[i][j]);
    }
    return C;
}

static void print_mtrx(const char *tag, int w, int N, int M, int **matrix)
{
    printf("%s (%dx%d):\n", tag, N, M);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
            printf("%*d", w, matrix[i][j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    enum { EX2_SIZE = 3, EX3_SIZE = 3 };
    int f_matrix[EX2_SIZE][EX2_SIZE] = { {1, 2, 3}, {1, 4, 7}, {1, 5, 9} };
    int s_matrix[EX2_SIZE][EX2_SIZE] = { {9, 8, 7}, {4, 5, 6}, {0, 9, 6} };
    int m1_rows = EX2_SIZE, m1_cols = EX2_SIZE;
    int m2_rows = EX2_SIZE, m2_cols = EX2_SIZE; // For tester can change easily
    int *f[] = { &f_matrix[0][0], &f_matrix[1][0], &f_matrix[2][0] };
    int *s[] = { &s_matrix[0][0], &s_matrix[1][0], &s_matrix[2][0] };
    int **new_matrix;

    if (m1_rows != m2_rows || m1_cols != m2_cols)
        return 0;

    print_mtrx("F", 3, EX2_SIZE, EX2_SIZE, f);
    print_mtrx("S", 3, EX3_SIZE, EX3_SIZE, s);

    new_matrix = multiplying(f, s, m1_rows, m1_cols);
    print_mtrx("R", 3, m1_rows, m1_cols, new_matrix);
    free_mtrx(new_matrix, m1_cols);

    return 0;
}
```

Granted, the 'matrix multiplication' algorithm isn't the conventional mathematical one; that's not a major issue.  The key point is that `int **matrix` is not the same as `int matrix[N][M]`.  The latter consists solely of integer values; the former is an array of pointers, each of which points to a series of integer values.  With the prototype for `multiplying()` in scope, the compiler complained about your original calls.  I manufactured the array of pointers from the arrays of integers when creating the matrices `f` and `s` from `f_matrix` and `s_matrix`.  Note that the body of the `print_mtrx()` function is identical to the body of the `print_matrix()` functions in the previous two programs.  However, the code generated is not the same because the argument lists use two different, incompatible types for the matrix argument.  [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) gives this program a clean bill of health.

Output:

```
F (3x3):
  1  2  3
  1  4  7
  1  5  9
S (3x3):
  9  8  7
  4  5  6
  0  9  6
R (3x3):
  9 16 21
  4 20 42
  0 45 54
```

Comment: First of all, thank you. second. i try to free like this:

void free_mtrx(int **mtrx, int rows) {
 int i;
 for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
  free(mtrx[i]);
 free(mtrx);
}

when my main is have "int **matrix" that get the result matrix. Now i get error to free matrix[i]  why is that ?

Comment: In your code in the question, you define `multiplying()` to return an `int` and yet return an `int **`; that should be generating squawks of horror from your compiler.  It could also lead to problems if `sizeof(int) != sizeof(int **)`. Given how you allocate the result matrix, your `free_mtrx()` function looks correct; free each row and then the pointer to the rows.  Presumably, you've got a problem of some sort with it, though, or you'd not mention it.

Comment: Also, your `multiplying` is defined to take two `int **` source matrices, but a 2D matrix like those in the `main()` code are not equivalent to `int **` — there is no array of pointers.  Again, your compiler should be complaining.

Comment: I'm using VS 17, in Debug i get an breakpoint when i'm getting into free(matrix[i])

Comment: Please don't change the code in the question after you've accepted an answer.  Add revised code (leaving the original, suitably annotated) if you must, but normally, you wouldn't change the code (except for formatting) and would only make editorial rather than substantive changes to commentary.  If you add new code, then adding new commentary is "OK".  You'd still normally not change the question after accepting an answer.  Also, please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  You've given code fragments — my answer shows a couple of 'close to MCVE' programs.

Comment: Is thak ok now ?

Comment: Yes; you could add the `free_mtrx()` code too, and maybe the `print_mtrx()` code.  Do you have a prototype for `multiplying()` in scope before you call it?  You should.  The compiler would then complain about your calls to the function.  You aren't ignoring compiler warnings, are you?  The compiler only warns when it has found a bug in your code.  The compiler knows more about C than you do (or I do).  Assume it's right if it warns.

Comment: See the additional information in my updated answer.  Note how I created the `f` and `s` matrices for the `int **` notation.